# Employment contract specifies 40 hours. Normal?

Tags: contracts, canada, employment, hours

Recently I received an offer for a Project Management position at IT company.
Before I've been working for about 6 years as a contractor/freelancer, and also I've never been working as an employee in Canada(Ontario) (we moved here from a different country).
In the offer, I have a clause that I have to work a minimum of 40 hours a week, and, if needed, more as the business will require. Guys, I wonder is it common in Canada(or more specific in Ontario) to include "hours" for such position?
Thank you.

Comment: It seems a reasonable clause, you get a salary, they want 40 hours minimum. What is your problem with that? What happens if they don't give you 40 hours of work to do though?

Comment: They don't give me work. There is a team that I should lead. I set goals and we need to reach them.  My concern is that they will start to measure how many hours I "gave them" instead of measuring mine and my team's output. Before I always had contracts with requirements that should be implemented - never had this "hours" thing

Comment: The "hours thing" is typically referred to as "employment". Most jobs require butts in chairs, with the idea being that if you can do your job in less time, then you should be doing more with the rest of the time too.

Comment: Yes, it is common. Expect to work much more than 40 hours and not to be paid overtime

Comment: Find me a job where you can leave as soon as your work is done for the day. Every salaried or waged job I've done or know about assumes that you'll stay for at least a set number of hours no matter what; sometimes with fixed hours to start and finish, sometimes flexible working where you add up your total hours. You can't just say "I've finished, I'm taking a half-day."

Answer (score 6):

Freelancing and contract work is often measured by output and results.

Many if not most jobs are judged and remunerated based on hours. It's perfectly normal to do so.

> My concern is that they will start to measure how many hours I "gave them" instead of measuring mine and my team's output.

They should be doing both. But in any case if you want the job you do it by the companies rules, or negotiate different ones. In most cases it's not really negotiable unless there is a special reason.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's perfectly normal. Salaried jobs generally expect 40 hours' work, and more when necessary to get the work done.

The "minimum of 40" wording is in there probably not for you, but because the people who wrote it have had trouble with slackers in the past. If you're not a slacker you'll be fine.

It's a good idea to ask your hiring manager about workday expectations, even before you accept the offer. Do they want to see you show up at particular time, take a lunch break at another time, and go home at a third time?  Do they expect you to be on a conference call with contractors in Asia at 6am or 7pm? If so they will tell you.  If they don't care they'll tell you. Flexible workdays might be good in a big city; you can work early or late to avoid rush hour traffic.

Good luck.